# how to resolve form styles between different languages, such as English and Chinese

Tags: css, forms

In web development, it is often necessary to deal with internationalization.
So, how to deal with the style problem caused by the uncertainty of the width of the Label in different languages with Form?

Edit：
I wonder if I can use CSS to dynamically calculate the width required by the Label and be adaptive.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc Share your code if you need help with adjustment, and If this won't do it - you will need to add javascript for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a matter of design rather than a technical issue. To support i18n sometimes you need to change your approach in this case I've seen designers putting labels above form fields to let them grow based on the amount of characters that each language requires. Designs always need to accommodate to i18n *(internationalization)* and a11y *accessibility* standards. And also keep in mind RTL and LTR designs and css class modifiers.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

[image: Forms example]

Comment: Yes, what you said is very reasonable.
But here, it is mainly curious whether CSS can be used to dynamically calculate the width required by the Label and be adaptive.

Comment: You can always use the `<html lang="">` attribute as a modifier to change the with of your `label` css selectors e.g. 
`html[lang=fr] label { width: 1rem; }` `html[lang=zh-Hans] label { width: 1.5rem; }`

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to set different css depending on the language. However, there is one thing that is not satisfactory. If you support 10 languages, each FormItem needs to set 10 styles, which is a lot of work. If you can automatically scale according to the maximum width of the left Lable, it would be fine.